# WPF DataGrid - How to replace blue row highlight with check box select?

Tags: wpf, xaml, wpfdatagrid

By default when you select a row on a DataGrid in WPF a blue highlight is made visible on the row.

For my DataGrid I have a column with a checkbox for each row. When a row is selected the box should be checked and no distracting blue highlight shows up.

Anyone know a way to do this?
I have tried this code but I don't know how to implement my checkbox column

```
    <DataGrid x:Name="dataGrid" BorderThickness="2" Margin="8,125,139,8" ColumnHeaderHeight="24" HorizontalGridLinesBrush="#FF009444" VerticalGridLinesBrush="#FF009444" BorderBrush="#FF009444" Background="White" RowHeight="20" FontFamily="Segoe UI Light" FontSize="14.8" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CanUserReorderColumns="False" CanUserResizeColumns="False" CanUserSortColumns="False" HeadersVisibility="Column" CanUserResizeRows="False" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" Padding="0">

        <DataGrid.CellStyle>
            <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
                <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="2" />
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="White" />
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black" />
                        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0" />
                        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#FF009444" />
                    </Trigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </DataGrid.CellStyle>


        <DataGrid.RowStyle>
            <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0" />
                        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#FF009444" />
                    </Trigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </DataGrid.RowStyle>

        <DataGrid.Resources>

            <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FF39B54A" />
                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#FF009444"/>
                <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0,0,2,2"/>
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
            </Style>
        </DataGrid.Resources>


        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="Column1" Header=" #" Binding="{Binding Name}" Width="20" IsReadOnly="True"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="Column2" Header=" Position" Binding="{Binding Name}" Width="90" IsReadOnly="True"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="Column3" Header=" Type" Binding="{Binding Name}" Width="71" IsReadOnly="True"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="Column4" Header=" Delay" Binding="{Binding Name}" Width="76" IsReadOnly="True"/>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn x:Name="Column5" Header=" [ ]" Width="20">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Name}"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
            <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="Column6" IsReadOnly="True" Header="Description" Binding="{Binding Name}" Width="584"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

Comment: Can you post the code you have tried?

Comment: So all you want to do is, when the row IsSelected=True, then IsChecked=True on the Checkbox? While also suppressing the gridcell style highlight? Just making sure I'm understanding the intent correctly.

Comment: Yeah I want the check box to act in the place of the blue highlight.

Comment: Please post full XAML of datagrid and by text, not image. Your image above is too little info.

Comment: Edited Sakura, that's the whole datagrid. I have added the columns I want and some cell and row styles. I have also added the checkbox column and suppressed the default select highlight. At this stage I am asking how to implement when the checkbox for a row is checked, that row is selected.

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way to do this, is to use DataGridCheckBoxColumn and override the selection style as below,

```
    <DataGrid Name="Grid" AutoGenerateColumns="False">            
        <DataGrid.Resources>
            <ResourceDictionary>
                <Style x:Key="{x:Type DataGridCell}" TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black" />
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{x:Null}" />
                    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{x:Null}" />                       
                </Style>
            </ResourceDictionary>
        </DataGrid.Resources>            

        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Header="Bool property" Binding="{Binding Path=IsSelected, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGridRow}}}"></DataGridCheckBoxColumn>                
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Text Property" Binding="{Binding .}"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>            
    </DataGrid>
```

Comment: Wow, seems to work pretty good. However if I try to uncheck a box it crashes with this message: An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in PresentationFramework.dll

Additional information: 'EditItem' is not allowed for this view.